# Powershell will not allow ServerCertificateValidationCallback change

Tags: powershell

I'm try to make a call with Invoke-RestMethod but the server I'm connecting to has a self-signed certificate.

After some searching I found that I need to run the following to make it work:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ${true}
```

I did this a couple of days ago and then my Invoke-RestMethod call started working.

I then rebooted my server and tried to execute the same again but now I get the following error:

> PS C:\Users\Administrator> [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = $True
>   Exception setting "ServerCertificateValidationCallback": "Cannot convert value "True" to type
>   "System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback". Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.Boolean' to
>   'System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback'.""
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = $True
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
>   Blockquote

I've tried setting my execution policy to unrestricted but I still have the same problem.

I'm running on Windows Server 2012 with PSVersion 3.0.

I've no idea why it worked before. I'm pretty sure there was nothing special i had done previously.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a website that had the following command:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

Note that 'System.' is missing.

Running this command worked as expected.

Comment: Correct command: [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}

Comment: @Der_Meister this seems to be identical to my answer.

Comment: No, dollar sign is located in wrong place in your answer.